# Why am I desynced in Singleplayer?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I was messing around in Education edition the other day, and summoned a few Ender Dragons with /summon while in survival mode.

One Ender Dragon got stuck in the bedrock layer, and I went to check it out. Immediately after going near the dragon, my whole game started acting up. I can't pick up items, use fireworks, eat, place blocks, take damage, hit mobs, or travel outside of the chunks that I already loaded. If I try to throw an item, it seems to disappear into nothingness and doesn't actually fall onto the ground. This includes throwing splash potions using right click. Mobs seem to not notice that I'm around, and I can't push entities either.

I can still mine blocks, but the block breaking animation won't show and the block will simply disappear without dropping anything. I can get into elytra mode and sprint around, but that's practically all.

To make this more infuriating, my commands and chat won't register and I'm stuck in a hole at bedrock level.

What is going on?

Comment: As Banana97286 pointed out, it is probably lag. Note that server lag and fps drops are not always consistent or caused by each other. I can recommend you run /kill @e in an attempt to clear some lag but beyond that, the best you can do is re-log, before you have to consider deleting the world.

Comment: How can there be server lag if I'm playing in singleplayer?

Comment: Also, I said that commands don't work :(

Comment: Minecraft actually runs an internal server, even when you are in single player. But this doesn't really help if commands don't work...

Comment: @Diehe That's interesting, where can I find more info about the internal server?

Comment: "Internally, the game runs a server for single-player games, this was done in order to make the single-player game experience consistent with the multiplayer experience and make it so that changes made to the game such as bug fixes apply to both single-player games and multiplayer games." This is a quote from the [Minecraft Fandom Wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Server)

Comment: Also, keep in mind it may be because the above internal server has crashed. However, I am not knowledgeable enough to confirm, deny, or provide any solutions to that.

Answer (score -1):

The most likely thing you are experiencing is lag. Because of all the ender dragons, your game is lagging, causeing you to not being able to open chat and do other things. This will happen especially on consoles such as Nintendo Switch, or if you are using a mobile device. Try closing the game and rejoining the world to fix the problem, but if that doesn't work, you may have to just delete the world.

Comment: There's only two ender dragons, and I'm getting 200 fps...